# httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: django, openapi

I'm trying to generate api client from my custom api with this [package](https://pypi.org/project/openapi-python-client/0.13.1/)

I have generated the api client:

```
openapi-python-client generate --path example_api_client.yaml
```

Built the package with:

```
cd example_api_client/
poetry build -f wheel
```

Copied and installed:

```
pip install ./example_api_client-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

But when i try to do a request throw the error:

```
httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The script is Django custom command:

```
from example_api_client.api.authentication import authentication_user_list
from example_api_client.models.user import User
from example_api_client.client import Client

class Command(BaseCommand):
  def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    BASE_URL = 'http://0.0.0.0:8002'
    client = Client(base_url=BASE_URL, verify_ssl=False, raise_on_unexpected_status=True)
    response: User = authentication_user_list.sync(client=client)
```

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your API server actually running at `http://0.0.0.0:8002`?

Comment: Yes, through postman request i can access to the endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

Inside docker network the services are available through internal IP.

docker-compose.yml:

```
...
django:
  ...
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  ports:
    - '8002:8000'
```

- From outside connection have to point to `0.0.0.0:8002`
- From inside connection have to point to `django:8000`